# Is there any way to decrease consumer lag while using Apache beam KafkaIO.readFromKafka?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, azure-eventhub

I want to consume approx 200GB of Data in the day from **Azure EVENT HUB** to publish to **Pubsub Topic** For which I have deployed the below dataflow job.

**Desired  Processing** **Rate**:  2314814 B/s  or 2.3 MB/s
**Current Processing Rate**:  408000 B/s 0.408 MB/s

**Machine type** :  `n1-standard-2`
**maxNumWorkers** :  `4`
**apache_beam :** `2.46.0`
**Runner v2**: `Enabled`
**Streaming Engine** :`Enabled`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, SetupOptions, StandardOptions


class encode(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        """
        Record attributes passed from ReadFromKafka transform:  'topic', 'value'
            'count', 'headers', 'index', 'key', 'offset', 'partition',
            'timestamp', 'timestampTypeId', 'timestampTypeName'.

        :return: Message value as string
        """
        if hasattr(element, 'value'):
            value = element.value
        elif isinstance(element, tuple):
            value = element[1]
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('unknown record type: %s' % type(element))
        yield value.encode("UTF-8") if isinstance(value, bytes) == False else value


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    global cloud_options
    global custom_options

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    kafka_consumer_config = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'Event-hub-name.servicebus.windows.net:9093',
        'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
        'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
        "sasl.jaas.config": 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Password";',
        'group.id': 'reporting',
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
        'enable.auto.commit': 'True',
        'max.poll.records': '180000', 
        'session.timeout.ms': '45000',
        'max.partition.fetch.bytes': '600000',
        'fetch.max.bytes': '28000000',
        'fetch.max.wait.ms': '500',
        'fetch.min.bytes': '8000000',
        'receive.buffer.bytes': '-1'
    }

    pubsub_topic = 'projects/gcp_project_name/topics/pubsub_topic_name'
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    (p
     | "read from kafka" >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config=kafka_consumer_config, topics=['products'],
                                          with_metadata=False)
     | 'encode the message ' >>  beam.ParDo(encode())
     | "Publish to Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(pubsub_topic)
     )
    p.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Following Kafka Consumer Parameters tweeked

```
'max.poll.records': '180000', 
'session.timeout.ms': '45000',
'max.partition.fetch.bytes': '600000',
'fetch.max.bytes': '28000000',
'fetch.max.wait.ms': '500',
'fetch.min.bytes': '8000000',`
```

Please suggest how can i achieve the  2.3 MB/s throughPut from ReadFromKafka

Answer (score 1):

The primary limiter on Kafka throughput in general is the number of partitions of a topic. I'd recommend increasing the number of partitions on your Kafka topic, so that Beam can scale up.

In addition, I'd recommend a higher cap on the maximum number of machines, for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could check the job metrics (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf) as well when tuning the parameters for Kafka.